# Why does using overflow give me this problem?

Tags: css, html-table, scrollbar, css-position, overflow

I have got a table with a scroll with the style "overflow-x:visible" to the scroll. But when I move the horizontal scroll It look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H51ud.jpg)
I tried applying position : absolute and the overflow problem was solved but the table pasted with the bottom of the top div and the first table header's name dissapear, looking like this [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfBPe.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mayank for your answer, I make the changes but the problem persists, because now I have two horizontal scrollbars, one always visible but too short to show all the table and the other only appears on the bottom of the table and it's only visible if you move down using the lateral scrollbar.

[In the first screenshot, you can see the double scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a68FH.jpg)

[In the second screenshot, you can see that in the top of the table you can't see the other columns but the scrollbar is to short to use it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRCP3.jpg)

Comment: if you share your code here, that would be better to understand this issue.